# Read an integer from stdin (in C)

Tags: c, stdin

I want to write a C program that takes as input an integer, and outputs its square. Here is what I have tried.

However,

- `./a.out < 3` outputs 32768, and
- `./a.out < 4` also outputs 32768.

Where am I wrong? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int myInt;
  scanf("%d", &myInt);
  printf("%d\n",myInt*myInt);
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to pass a filename as the redirection source and that file contains the required text input. So if `my.txt` contains `4` the command `./a.out < my.txt` will output `16`.

Comment: If you are using Bash, you can also use `program <<< input`, which is equivalent to `echo input | program`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is

```
echo 4 | ./a.out
```

the syntax for < is

```
program < input_file
```

whereas | is

```
command_with_output | program
```

Answer (score 1):

On the right hand side of "<", there should be a file containing the input.

try this thing:

$ echo "3" > foo
$ ./a.out < foo

Read this for more information (Specially section 5.1.2.2):
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/chap_05.html

Answer (score 1):

```
./a.out < 4
```

This tries to read the file named 4 and use it's content as input to `a.out` You can do it whichever way, but understand the `<` operator isn't for inputting the character you type quite literally.

One way to do this would be:

```
echo "4" > 4
./a.out < 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I just run your program and its works great.
If you want the program receive an integer input you should use argc , argv as folowed and not use scanf.

***The code for argc argv: ***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
  int myInt;
    myInt = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("%d\n",myInt*myInt);
}
```

atoi - convert char* to integer.

If you want to run the program and then insert an integer, you did it right!
[you can read about atoi](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

To run this program you should comile and run from terminal:

```
gcc a.c -o a    
./a 3
```

and you will receive:

```
9
```